# Kotlin star projection on contravariant types

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, types, type-projection

I am reading and trying to understand Kotlin type projections, sometimes I come up with confusing things like this:

> **For contravariant type parameters such as `Consumer<in T>`, a star
> projection is equivalent to `<in Nothing>`. In effect, you can’t call
> any methods that have `T` in the signature on such a star projection.**
> If the type parameter is contravariant, it acts only as a consumer,
> and, as we discussed earlier, you don’t know exactly what it can
> consume. Therefore, you can’t give it anything to consume.
>
> You can use the star projection syntax when the information about type
> arguments isn’t important: you don’t use any methods that refer to the
> type parameter in the signature, or you only read the data and you
> don’t care about its specific type. For instance, you can implement
> the `printFirst` function taking `List<*>` as a parameter.

What does it mean to contravariant type to have a star projection and how does it come up to

Comment: You answered your own question - a star projection is using `*` instead of a type. This is specified later in your screenshot. [Here's a link on co-/contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) in C# (it's the same concept, but I think MSDN explains it quite well.) [Here's the Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html). This just means that writing `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<in Nothing>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is also explained in the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections):

> For `Foo<in T>`, where `T` is a **contravariant** type parameter, **`Foo<*>`** is equivalent to `Foo<in Nothing>`. It means there is *nothing you can write to* `Foo<*>` in a safe way when `T` is unknown.

#### Example

We have a class `Foo<T>` with contravariant `T` (declaration-site), i.e. `Foo` only works as a consumer of `T`:

```
class Foo<in T> {
    fun accept(t: T) {
        println(t)
    }
}
```

We can use this type in simple generic functions as follows:

```
fun <F> usingFoo(con: Foo<F>, t: F) {
    con.accept(t)
}
```

(used `F` in order to distinguish from class type parameter `T`)

This works fine since we use `Foo` as intended: As a consumer of `T`s.

Now, your quote simply says that having a parameter of type `con: Foo<*>`  instead of `con: Foo<T>` would have the following effect: *"you can't call any methods that have `T` in the signature"*.

Thus, the following fails:

```
fun <F> usingFoo(con: Foo<*>, t: F) {
    con.accept(t) //not allowed!!
}
```

It's not safe to call `accept` with an instance of `F` because we don't know the type of `Foo` (denoted by **star projection**).

> **Star Projection**: Sometimes you want to say that you know nothing about the type argument, but still want to use it in a safe way. The safe way here is to define such a projection of the generic type, that every concrete instantiation of that generic type would be a subtype of that projection.

Answer (score 11):

Let's understand the reason *why* the star projection for contravariant `Consumer<in T>` is equivalent to `<in Nothing>`. But before that, we need to understand what exactly is a star projection and how it is for covariant `Producer<out T>`.

---

### Star Projection

When you use a star projection of some generic class, you are not interested in using the functions or properties that return `T` or accept `T` as arguments from that generic class. For example, the following function just returns the bigger `List` of the two. We are only interested in the `size` property which doesn't return or accept `T`, it just returns an `Int`:

**Example**

```
fun getBiggerOfTwo(list1: MutableList<*>, list2: MutableList<*>) : MutableList<*> {
    return if (list1.size >= list2.size) list1 else list2
}
```

**Why use `*` instead of specifying a type?**

We want to keep the type unknown, so that we won't end up using the
`T` specific functions accidently. For example, in the above function, if we are allowed to call the `list1.add(Something())`, we might end up mutating the list accidentally where we just intend to compare the lists. So, the compiler will help us by flagging an error when we call the `add()` function. Apart from creating the safety, our function will also be reusable for various types, not just some specific type.

---

### Covariant without upper bound

In the following examples, we'll use the `Producer` and `Consumer` classes for producing and consuming various subtypes of `class Pet(val cutenessIndex: String)`:

**Declaration-site**

```
class Producer<out T> {
    private val items = listOf<T>()
    fun produce() : T = items.last()
    fun size(): Int = items.size
}
```

**Use-site**

```
fun useProducer(star: Producer<*>) {
    // Produces Any?, a Pet is not guaranteed because T is unknown
    val anyNullable = star.produce()      // Not useful

    // Can't use functions and properties of Pet.
    anyNullable.cutenessIndex             // Error

    // Can use T-independent functions and properties
    star.size()                           // OK
}
```

---

### Covariant with upper bound

**Declaration-site**

```
class Producer<out T : Pet> {
    private val pets = listOf<T>()
    fun produce() : T = pets.last()
}
```

**Use-site**

```
fun useProducer(star: Producer<*>) {
    // Even though we use * here, T is known to be at least a Pet
    // because it's an upper bound at the declaration site.
    // So, Pet is guaranteed.
    val pet = star.produce()              // OK

    // Can use properties and functions of Pet.
    pet.cutenessIndex                     // OK
}
```

---

### Contravariant without lower bound

**Declaration-site**

```
class Consumer<in T> {
    private val items = mutableListOf<T>()
    fun consume(item: T) = items.add(item)
    fun size(): Int = items.size
}
```

**Use-site**

```
fun useConsumer(consumer: Consumer<*>) {
    // Cannot consume anything because 
    // lower bound is not supported in Kotlin and T is unknown.
    consumer.consume(Pet())               // Error

    // Can use T-independent functions and properties.
    consumer.size()                       // OK
}
```

---

### Contravariant with lower bound

The lower bound is not supported in Kotlin. So, in the `Consumer` class above, we cannot have something like `in Pet : T`(lower bound) like we have `out T : Pet`(upper bound). As we know a consumer can consume `T` and it's subtypes. `Nothing` is the subtype of all types in Kotlin, just like `Any?` is the supertype of all types. And since, the `T` is unknown in the star projection, the only known subtype of `T` is `Nothing`. This is why a consumer's star projection can only consume `Nothing`. Hence, saying `Consumer<*>` is the same thing as saying `Consumer<in Nothing>`.

---

That's it! Hope that helps clearing things up.

Answer (score 4):

Further to answer above by user s1m..

```
class Foo<in T> {
    fun accept(t: T) {
        println(t)
    }

    fun doSomething(): String {
        return "yay"
    }
}

fun <F> usingFoo(con: Foo<*>, t: F) {
    //  con.accept(t) //not allowed!!
    val result = con.doSomething() // OK!
}

fun main() {
    val number: Int = 5
    usingFoo(Foo<Number>(), number)
}
```

In terms of using the

```
Foo<*>
```

in a safe way, the doSomething() method shows one example (the forbidden methods are those that consume type T).

Answer (score 0):

To add to sm1..'s superb answer, here is an example for covariant types:

```
   class Foo<out U: Number> {
        private var u: U? = null
            
        fun produce(): U? {
            return u
        }
    }
    
    fun usingFoo(foo: Foo<*>) {
        foo.produce()    
    }
    
    fun main() {    
        usingFoo(Foo<Number>()) //OK
        usingFoo(Foo<Any>()) // Not OK
        
//Direct calls (not using method with *)    
    Foo<Number>().produce() //OK
    Foo<Any>().produce() //Not OK  
       
    }
```

Same behaviour in direct calls without star projections, but the * basically says: we defined a generic type (Foo), and at the point of use in a method (usingFoo), we still don't know the concrete type. The original constraint of super type (in this case, Number), remains. The * just says: the concrete type is defined elsewhere.