# What's the correct way to declare a class property with generic bounds in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have an interface like this:

```
interface ItemClickListener<in T : Item> {
    fun onClick(item: T)
}
```

And I have a class somewhat like this:

```
abstract class MyClass {
    private var itemClickListener: ItemClickListener<*>? = null

    fun <I : Item> setOnClickListener(clickListener: ItemClickListener<I>) {
        this.itemClickListener = clickListener
    }
}
```

Later, if I want to use that listener it fails:

```
itemClickListener?.onClick(item)
```

I get:

> Out-projected type 'ItemClickListener<*>?' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun onClick(item: T): Unit defined in my.package.ItemClickListener'

What's the correct way to declare the itemClickListener property on my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) of star-projections:

> For `Foo<in T>`, where `T` is a contravariant type parameter, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<in Nothing>`. It means there is nothing you can write to `Foo<*>` in a safe way when `T` is unknown.

The error message happens because the star-projection of `ItemClickListener<in T: Item>` is `ItemClickListener<in Nothing>`, which cannot be called with any parameter. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172314/kotlin-star-projection-on-contravariant-types) also gives relevant information on it.

The solution would be to declare the field `itemClickListener` and the parameter of `setOnClickListener` as `ItemClickListener<Item>`, which would have the same variance as the class declaration `<in Item>`. You could therefore call `onClick` with any subtype of `Item`.

Comment: Thanks! That's the way I ended up doing :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to make `MyClass` generic, as well:

```
abstract class MyClass<out I : Item> {
    private var itemClickListener: ItemClickListener<I>? = null

    fun setOnClickListener(clickListener: ItemClickListener<I>) {
        this.itemClickListener = clickListener
    }
}
```

Now `itemClickListener` is typesafe and can be used as an `ItemClickListener<I: Item>` later on.